# Is it possible to dynamically extend the translations in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, internationalization

We have an app and in some cases we make things configurable through the server side administration.
For example, we want to offer users a Christmas greeting around Christmas, an Easter greeting at Easter, or even something to the current weather ...

is it possible to add new texts at runtime? We are vurrently using the "Flutter i18n - Plugin" /https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10128-flutter-i18n/

Answer (score 2):

Some localization platforms offer "Over the Air" solution for runtime translation updates.
This solution can be handy for correcting typos, optimizing texts, or updating translations on the fly. Unfortunately, this solution is not free of charge.

Potential workaround is to use **Select ICU** messages.

Example:

Define universal greeting message (expects upfront defined set of constants):

```
"greetingTypes": "{type, select, christmasGreeting {Happy Christmas!} easterGreeting {Happy Easter!} other {Welcome!}}",
"@greetingTypes": {
  "placeholders": {
    "type": {}
  }
}
```

Use previously defined message:

```dart
var type = response.greetingType; // fetch config from the backend

Text(
  S.of(context).greetingTypes(type),
)
```

Note, that if mentioned plugin doesn't support this kind of messages, you can use it with [Flutter Intl](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13666-flutter-intl) plugin for Android Studio or [Flutter Intl](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=localizely.flutter-intl) extension for VS Code.

Hope it helps!